# RemoteIO callback after AUMixer

Tags: iphone, audio, callback, effects, audiounit

What is the correct way to implement a callback on the RemoteIO after the aumixer has done it's thang.

If i use ;

result = AUGraphSetNodeInputCallback(mGraph, outputNode,1, &remoteIOCallback);

It doesn't call my function

If I use ..

result = AudioUnitSetProperty(mIONode, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback,                            kAudioUnitScope_Input,      1 , &remoteIOCallback,  sizeof(remoteIOCallback));

It calls my callback but when i try to create a pointer to the ioData

AudioSampleType *inData = (AudioSampleType *) ioData->mBuffers[0].mData;

it crashes.

I cannot see the problem at all. Is this a problem with the buffers? But then i'm not allocating anything to the buffer, just a pointer to it.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Instead of immediately casting to an AudioSampleType*, first try casting ioData to your custom data type. Then try accessing the data in the buffer.